# Configuration profiles in Universal Windows Platform and Android

Tags: android, uwp, mdm, configuration-profile

I've read that the Apple devices are managed by Mobile Device Management (MDM) servers using configuration profiles saved on the device. I also read somewhere that Android devices do not have a configuration profile. Then what is the alternate used to manage Android device? Also, please let me know about alternate to configuration profile in universal Windows platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Android, Google and device vendors offer native APIs, e.g. 'set up passcode' or 'wipe the device'. The middleware client on the device calls these.

On Windows platform, Microsoft offers CSPs, which are basically xml-wrapped API calls of a similar nature, you can say 'Configure exchange' or 'Install an App'.